# Calculated Column: change date format issue for all day events

Tags: 2013, calendar, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I discovered an strange behavior when I try to display a date/time in an other format within an calculated column.

The formula of the calculated column is: `=TEXT([End Time],"dd‑mmm‑yy")`
this transforms the value of the column `End Time` (e.g. *9/4/2016 11:59 PM*) to *04‑Sep‑16*.

As displayed here:
[image: all day]

The magic comes in when I set the `End Time` to an "All Day Event" (due to its an calendar entry). The exact same date/time combination (e.g. *9/**4**/2016 11:59 PM*) gets converted to *0**5**‑Sep‑16* - which is obviously wrong.

[image: not all day]

Any ideas why this is happening and how to avoid this conversion error?

Comment: This might be a bug.. I am not able to repro this in SharePoint Online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, all-day events actually use GMT. I'm on central time, so all-day events are always off by either 6 or 7 hours, depending on daylight savings.

**Workaround**

1. Create a single line of text field to hold a the end date in string format (e.g. `Workflow Date`)
2. Set the field using a workflow to the value of `End Time` returned as a string
3. Set your calculated date to `=TEXT([Workflow Date],"dd‑mmm‑yy")`

Comment: I guess you are right. If I'm using `=HOUR([End Time]` I get **1** (AM) insted of **11** (PM) which in my case is because I'm in UTC+2 right now.

Any suggestion how to handle the problem? I can't just use `DAY -1` due to some people working at UTC/GMT as well with this sharepoint list :/

Comment: The only solution I've found is not using all day events. I'll add a possible solution for your scenario to my answer.

Comment: thx for that, so u mean the end date should be added twice (the default ``calandar date`` and the "custom" ``workflow date``) by the user?

Comment: Calendar date will be entered by the user. The custom workflow date would be calculated by the workflow, and the user wouldn't need to know it exists.

Comment: ok I see. Can you give me some details about what to add to the workflow? I cannot find anything calendar related on "actions" within the workflow designer on SharePoint Designer 2013

Comment: The actions is `set field in current item`. Set `Workflow Date` to `End Time` as string.

Answer (score 0):

Chop off all time info

```
=TEXT( DATE( YEAR([End Time]) , MONTH([End Time]) , DAY([End Time]) ) , "dd‑mmm‑yy" )
```

Comment: unfortunately its not working. I even tried to use just `=DAY([End Time]` and its showing me **5** insted of the expected **4**. Very confusing :/